# Предлог "На" при указании на путь следования общественного транспорта

Tags: предлоги

В каких случаях возможно применение предлога "на" при указания пути следования автобуса, троллейбуса, трамвая?

В сочетании с улицей? "Автобус идёт на улицу Чусовская"
В сочетании с названиями магазинов, общественных зданий? "Трамвай идёт на 96-ю поликлинику", "Трамвай идёт на аптеку"

В каких случаях корректен этот предлог?

Comment: Эти примеры (типа «на Берлин») сочинение, или можете сослаться на источник?

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с "улицей" возможен (в отличие от двух других) по причине сочетаемости предлога "на" с "улицей" в выражении "**на** улице", обозначающем *местоположение*, - в данном случае предложная сочетаемость сохраняется и при указании конечного пункта (*куда*), *где* он окажется (на улице). Для сравнения: при указании местонахождения невозможны сочетания "на аптеке" и "на поликлинике", и требуется предлог **к** (аптеке, поликлинике), который возможен и в сочетании с "улицей", **к** которой автобус *приблизится*. Даже если эти объекты фигурируют как конечные пункты маршрута, нет возможности употребить их так, как это иногда возможно с населёнными пунктами ("на Москву" и т. п.).